# Aggregate operations on filtered rows

Tags: numbers

How do I perform aggregate functions on rows displayed after I filter a column? For example, if I wanted to append a row after the filtered rows that are displayed, and in that new row, have a sum of the previous rows that are the result of the filter, how would I do that?

If I simply add a row below the set of filtered rows and attempt to sum a column, *all* of the previous rows (not just those included by the filter) are summed.

Numbers 13, macOS 13.3.1(a)